# How do I capture the users id in the route?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

Let's say I want to route to `/api/user/:id/apikeys`

I currently have

```
/server
  /api
    /user
      [id].get
```

If I add an `apikeys` folder, how do I capture the users `id` in the route?

Comment: I figured it out You literally create a folder called `[id]` in the `user` folder and then create an `apikeys.get.ts` file inside of that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out You literally create a folder called `[id]` in the `user` folder and then create an `apikeys.get.ts` file inside of that.